# jquery placeholder form submit in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer, placeholder

I use this function for supporting placeholder in internet explorer:

```
function placeHolder() {
$('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
}).blur(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
        }
    })
});
```

}

I use :

```
.parents('form').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
        }
    })
```

to prevent from submitting input with placeholder value,

but It doesn't work,I search for other solutions but all of them has problem with form submitting ...

can everyone help me? I must use placeholder in ie...

thank you

Comment: We use [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) jQuery plugin for placeholders in IE.

Comment: @A1rPun I Previously use this jquery but it also has problem with form submit for example when I click on search button nothing found because search using placeholder value... :(

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/mNU4b/

Comment: @A1rPun It work,but I use update panel and this submit cause postback that I don't want...

Answer (score 0):

first of all detect that which browser is it. does it support placeholder?

for that use following code :

```
 if (($.support.placeholder = (function () { var i = document.createElement('input'); return 'placeholder' in i; })()) == false) {
```

Then give value to those input box with

```
 $('selector').val('abc')
```

hope..this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

on click of button, use jquery submit instead of javascript submit

```
$('#myForm').attr('action', 'value');

$("#myForm").submit();
```

Comment: Are you talking about disconnecting the button from the form?